# WPF poor rendering of application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have been working on a WPF C# application and there seems to be a bug when rendering the application.

Basically, I get random/various horizontal lines drawn through my application whenever the program is redrawn (window resized, change tabs in the program, etc).

Below is an image showing what I am seeing. The arrows show the random lines that are being drawn.

I assume that there is a simple solution to fix this, (simple addition of C# WPF code or a very simple trick that keeps everything refreshed), except I'm not sure what that line or trick is. Any ideas?

It seems like I just need to "flush" the screen canvas and redraw it.

[image: WPF Application Bugs]

--Edit--

## Working Model

Using the response from Erti-Chris Eelmaa, the problem was fixed. See both images below.

### Non-working

[image]

### Working

[image]

Comment: Could you please check if your graphic driver is up to date ? Is this happening on all pcs ?

Comment: First Thing I would do is to use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the running application and CTRL+Click over those lines to see what they really are.

Comment: WPF is not really the best framework to use when you want crisply-rendered interfaces and native-looking controls. It has trouble with a lot of video drivers, visual artifacts are common, and everything ranges from either slightly to extremely blurry—especially text. You should switch to something like WinForms or Win32 that get all of this basic behavior right. (@HighCore made me do it)

Comment: @CodyGray Extremely not true. We have 600+ customers as of today, each with a number of PCs between 3 and 10 running our product, and NOT A SINGLE TIME have we had reports of anything like this in our WPF Application. Completely Untrue and unbased.

Comment: The graphics driver on both of my development PCs were up-to-date (Win7 and Win8). I think it turned out to be a rendering thing.

Comment: Microsoft got more than enough complaints on Visual Studio 2010's WPF interface to make up for it. Besides, @HighCore, the accepted solution to this question provides some support for my claim. I've seen the problems myself. Some people are just less picky, and some machines just handle it better.

Comment: @CodyGray I guess that's why MS abandoned WPF in favor of this WinRT stuff now. I hope they fix it once and for all and they add all the stuff available in WPF to WinRT, so we can have at least 1 usable and performant framework =(. Otherwise I'll have to start coding Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try disabling GPU acceleration:
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;

Sometimes WPF GPU caching does a lot of tricks, and this can help, without degrading much performance imo.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st line (on top in your picture) looks like the result of having another control either below or on top of the active tab/tabcontrol. Make sure you do not have unwanted controls/FrameworkElements.
As far as the 2nd line (bottom of your picture), I believe that is part of the TabControl Header. You can get rid of it by styling the TabControl.